# Is there good .sol editor for Flash Player 9 Local Shared Objects? Can we build one?

Tags: flash, actionscript

There's plenty of them out there but none of them do what I would like them to do.

Most of them crash when opening a file or simply corrupt the data. Many don't run at all. It seems to me that most were written 3-4 years ago for AS2 .sols and no longer work with FP9/AS3 sols. I'd attempt to write my own using AIR but I can't find a new spec of the byte format.

There's an explanation of the file format here:
http://sourceforge.net/docman/display_doc.php?docid=27026&group_id=131628

and another here:
http://sourceforge.net/docman/display_doc.php?docid=27026&group_id=131628

but it looks as though both of these docs are a good 4 years old (pre-FP9) and as I'm not skilled or experienced in file formats,  writing a new one, especially without an updated spec, is seeming like less and less of a viable option.

Ideally I'd like one that can not only read the .sol, but edit and save new values also.

Thanks!

Comment: The wikipedia article on the topic of LSOs provides a robust list of currently available SOL editors: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_shared_object#Editors_and_toolkits

Answer (score 6):

Use [minerva](http://blog.coursevector.com/minerva). I've tried it, it works with every .sol I open it with.

Answer (score 2):

Flash originally serialized data into a format called AMF, and with version 9+ uses an updated version called AMF3. While the AMF specs are open (the AMF3 spec is [here](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/labs/amf/amf3_spec_121207.pdf)), I don't think Adobe has opened the format of SOL files themselves. (Also, I think that SOL files written partially by v9+ players may contain both AMF0 and AMF3 data.)

As for existing apps/frameworks, it looks like [PyAMF](http://pyamf.org/wiki/LocalSharedObject) is your best bet, as it's the only one I found after a quick browse that claims to grok both AMF0 and AMF3. I haven't personally used it however.

Comment: thanks! I'll look at the AMF specs and see if that helps. The pyAMF looks like it could do what I need it to do but I don't have access to a Python server. However if they could do it that gives me hope that it can be done in another language too. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The newest version of minerva 3.2.1 does allow both open/read and write/save for .sol files and works with AS3. I know none of the other programs mentioned would work for saving .sol files.

Answer (score 1):

@ Another_Castle,

The poster was wanting an editor that could both read and write shared object files.  While I do like minerva, it clearly states on the site that there is a bug saving AMF3 format files.
I have tried every program listed here to no avail and it seems that there is not an editor out there capable of saving amf3 format files after editing consistently.  If someone has one please post it here.

Comment: exactly, thank you. I would love in minerva went OSS or if someone made one that worked. What i've found is a lot of "sort-of-works" stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on debian based linux, I can use this program in WINE and it works great

http://sourceforge.net/projects/soleditor/

Good luck

Comment: I can confirm that this solution is still working in 2023

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused, isn't the best editor for Flash 9 shared objects... Flash? It already has methods for loading, editing and saving them.

---

So make the editor and put it on your website. You won't get any security errors from flash, and then just throw a password around it so regular people can't edit their .sol files.

---

Yes, they are restricted by domain, so it'd have to live on the publishers sites. If you have hundreds of clients, that might be an issue, but if you have 3 or 4... It's certainly easier than coding your own file format parser.

Comment: true, but what I'd like to do is open and edit the data in any .sol file on my hard drive.  what we're trying to do is allow my group of developers to manually toggle an FSO so that we can enable a setting on our publisher sites to view our API's logs.

Comment: how? aren't they restricted by domain? if I put it on my own site, and my publishers are a variety of sites, then i won't be able to edit the FSOs from their sites, due to the security restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Sephiroth's SOL Reader?

http://www.sephiroth.it/python/solreader.php

I haven't used the new version (written in C#, with support for AMF0 and AMF3 ) but the previous one used to be fine.

PD: Out of curiosity, I just downloaded the new version and tried it. It crashed on every single SOL I tried to open. Too bad, it used to be a very nice editor...

Comment: yeah, I tried them all and none of them worked right, if they worked at all.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.sephiroth.it/python/solreader.php

I currently use this program. it works great

Answer (score 0):

have you checked SolVE http://solve.sourceforge.net/ ... it's good, it's free, it runs on OSX and Windows, and it was developed by a kick ass Flash developer

Cheers,

Comment: I honestly can't remember, since it's been so long since I asked this question (I'm not even at the job where this was required anymore.) But If i recall correctly, this one of the doesn't-work ones that prompted this question. According to the site, it hasn't been updated since 2004, which means there is no way it can edit AVM2 .sols.