# How to parse flash cookies (.SOL files) with JAVA

Tags: java, actionscript-3, apache-flex, amf, local-shared-object

Is there a JAVA library/class which provides parsing capabilities for Flash cookie files (.SOL) by any chance?

The user case scenario is quite simple:
Given a *.SOL file I need to read all the text info (programmatically).

PS.: From a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64170/is-there-good-sol-editor-for-flash-player-9-local-shared-objects-can-we-build) someone figured out that SOL files format is based on AMF, however I would like to know whether Adobe has opened the format or not.

Thanks a lot,

--Max

Answer (score 1):

Any of the following libraries claim to do the work:

- AMF48AMF Encode/Decode Library for Java
  http://amf48.develop.jp/en/download
- AMF-serializer
  http://code.google.com/p/amf-serializer/downloads/detail?name=amf-serializer-1.0.0.zip&can=2&q=
- Open AMF
  http://programmaremobile.blogspot.com/2009/10/java-and-amf-by-as3-in-flash.html

Comment: Here is the technical specification: http://download.macromedia.com/pub/labs/amf/amf3_spec_121207.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Not that I am aware of.

I'm not sure if it's an open format or not but this software certainly seems to read them from the harddrive
http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/flash_cookies_view.html

More info on wikipedia including a list of software reading them
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Shared_Object

this claims to translate sol files to xml... you might be able to use this easily in Java
http://osflash.org/s2x

Comment: Your approach seems to work, but I was looking for a solution such as the following ones...